# Android How to retrieve value of Dynamically added Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am dynamically adding the Spinners in my application by parsing the XML file.

I have done using the below code

```
List<Spinner> allspin = new ArrayList<Spinner>();
Spinner spin = new Spinner(getParent());
allspin.add(spin);
spin.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
     LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getParent(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, selectval);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Spinners are displayed correctly but i don't know how to retrieve the value of selected spinner. If there is one spinner i can retieve, but there are multiple how should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the reference of the spinner from your arraylist like this :

```
Spinner spn = allspin.get(index);
```

After that you can get the selected item by simply calling:

```
spn.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set id of spinner dynamically.

For that,you can use

```
spin.setId(i); //if you use i of for loop for creating multipal spin at a tym or you can use a global variable i,incremented by one each time you create a spinner
```

and further,you can use those ids to get values from particular spinner.

Example:

```
for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
{
    Spinner spin=new Spinner(getApplicationCotext());
    spin.setId(i);
    ...
    //other code
    ...
    mLayout.add(spin);//add this spinner to your layout(mLayout is object of your layout in xml)
}
```

Now,

```
for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
{
    Spinner sp=(Spinner)findViewById(i);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

            System.out.println(sp.getText().toString());//prints values of a pinner when it is changed/selected 
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need multiple spinners (I'm not sure I understand your use case), then, as you're creating each of them, you need to also create the appropriate listeners. You shouldn't have to retrieve values of spinners yourself; handling these selection events should be done in your listeners. Perhaps if you explained what you're attempting to do a bit better it would be easier to help...