# Reading values of dynamically generated spinners - how to do this?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, spinner, listener

In my layout there is a number of spinners generated and added programmatically this way:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < spinnerCount; i++) {

        spinner = new Spinner(this);
        spinner.setId(i);
        spinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(SpinnerLayout.this, R.layout.row, strings));
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinnerContainer.addView(spinner);
    }
```

Everything seems to work fine until I want to get values of each spinner. The listener only returns the value of the last spinner. How to make it read value of each spinner? Eventually, I'd like to have all the values stored in a predefined array (so, the looped method `spinnerValues.set(int position, int spinnerVal);` is taken into account.

*This is a follow-up of this thread: [Multiple spinners in an activity...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307636/multiple-spinners-in-an-activity-can-it-be-refactored-to-make-it-generated-dyn)*

Moreover, I found a very similar issue here: [How to retrieve value of Dynamically added Spinner...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117355/android-how-to-retrieve-value-of-dynamically-added-spinner/8117402#8117402), but when trying to apply the linked answer, I get an error saying my spinner variable is not final (well, it shouldn't be in this case...). Any hints, Guys?

Comment: if u can't make your spinner final you can make it global..so that it can be accessed into an inner class.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @bakriOnFire. If I didn't decide to solve this issue with array approach, I'd move this way (made first steps with it though). But anyway, I'll keep this piece of advice in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may keep a reference to each Spinner in an array and in the listener loop through it and get value for each one.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
 for(Spinner s : spinners){
   // s.getSelectedItem()
 }
}
```

You can also perform check on which one has been changed by comparing the IDs.

```
parent.getId() == s.getId()
```

Otherwise you may look through all spinners in the ViewGroup:

```
int count = spinnerContainer.getChildCount();
for(int i =0;i<count;i++)
{
    View v = spinnerContainer.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof Spinner)
    {
        ((Spinner)v).getSelectedItem()
    }
}
```

Lastly you could also instantiate different listener for each one.